# Safe way to update a mysql table entry with a dictionary in python (safeguarding against SQL injection)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-injection, mysql-connector

I am writing a helper function for my webapp that updates the database based on some information that is fetched from a foreign API (not user entered). I have the following code, but it was flagged as 'unsafe' by the [Bandit](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html) python package.

Ideally I could write a function in a way that the columns to be updated are hardcoded, but I think it should also be possible dynamically.

Is this a safe way (no possibility for sql injections) to update a table?

```
import mysql.connector as database

def update_message_by_uid(uid: str, update_dict: dict) -> None:

    # Fetches the previous entry from the database using the unique identifier
    message_info_dict = get_message_by_uid(uid)

    # check that all the keys of the update dict are also in the original dict
    assert set(update_dict.keys()) <= set(
        message_info_dict.keys()
    ), "Some of the keys in the dictionary passed are not valid database columns"

    # We update the entry for all entries in the dictionary containing the updates
    statement = 'UPDATE messages SET {}  WHERE uid = %s'.format(", ".join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in update_dict))


    # Concatenates the values of the dict with the unique identifier to pass it to the execution method as one variable
    data = list(update_dict.values()) + [uid]

    cursor.execute(statement, data)
```

Comment: Your code is not very optimal but safe. Those vulnerability scanners are quite dumb.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the column name in back-ticks, in case a column name is an [SQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/keywords.html) or contains whitespace or punctuation or international characters. Also make sure a literal back-tick character in the column name is replaced with two back-ticks.

```
assignments = ", ".join(f"`{k.replace('`', '``')}`=%s" for k in update_dict)
statement = f"UPDATE messages SET {assignments}  WHERE uid = %s"
```

I'd prefer using f-strings instead of format().